# Why is Law of Large Numbers a Law and Central Limit Theorem a Theorem... when they look like the opposites?

Tags: logic

In probabilities, the Law of Large Numbers (which has a "weak" and a "strong" version) tells that the more samples you take of a fact (under a model you state), the closer you are to the actual mean of your model (in this case, you don't know the mean, and want to know it via your sampling). You get the true mean when you make a complete census instead of a sampling.

This argument is not arbitrary: the variance of the sampling average tends to 0 as it increases, and when your variance is 0, you reach the true value. This is: **it has a mathematical proof**.

Also in probabilities, the Central Limit Theorem tells that when you add a lot of independent and identically distributed random variables, your distribution will get closer to a **normal** distribution (while you don't know the average/variance of the data beforehand, your distribution will be of average=`n*theUnknownAverage` and variance=`n*theUnknownVariance`).

While looking for a formal demonstration of the theorem, what I see is a visual demonstration, like *look this visually! it tends to the shape of a normal, the more I add data*.

I use to have as a concept... that a theorem has a formal demonstration under the model and its axioms, and a law arises from observations that appear to somehow just occur and be true.

So... why is LLN a Law and CLT a Theorem and not swapped ("Theorem of Large Numbers", "Central Limit Law")? What am I missing here?

Comment: You should have asked it on Math SE. They are both theorems, the naming is an accident of history (the "law" was empirically observed long before it was proved). The law only tells you what happens in the limit to the averages (means), whereas the central limit theorem (CLT) is much stronger, it tells you what happens to the entire distributions. The law is its simple corollary.  There is a [formal proof of CLT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_limit_theorem#Proof_of_classical_CLT), visual shapes are just an illustration.

Comment: Adding to @Conifold's comment, the use of the term 'theory' didn't really come into vogue until the late 19th or early 20th century. Prior to that, people tended to talk about 'natural laws'. That was more a shift in the philosophical understanding of science than an analytical distinction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is only an historical convention.

Well... the [Central Limit Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_limit_theorem) is a theorem; see e.g [Classical CLT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_limit_theorem#Classical_CLT).

Also the [Law of large numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_large_numbers) is a theorem; maybe, the reason why it is called a "law" is because (like many early probability theory results) originated with some sort of "empirical observations" :

> the Italian mathematician Gerolamo Cardano (1501–1576) stated without proof that the accuracies of empirical statistics tend to improve with the number of trials. This was then formalized as a law of large numbers. A special form of the LLN (for a binary random variable) was first proved by Jacob Bernoulli. It took him over 20 years to develop a sufficiently rigorous mathematical proof which was published in his *Ars Conjectandi* in 1713. He named this his "Golden Theorem" but it became generally known as "Bernoulli's Theorem".